# MapView is very slow, many pins

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview

I have made an app that places a pin on a mapview, and i need to place around 9000pins.

Now when i zoom out it gets sooooooooooo slow. I'm not sure but is there a way to somehow make it faster? It's okay when it's zoomed in a abit, but when I can see more like around 2000-3000 it starts to lag. The more I zoom out the slower it gets.

I'm not sure if there is, maybe I'm coding it wrong. It could be awesome if you guys could fill me in.

The code I'm using to pin with coordinates:

```
point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];

newCoord.latitude = [coordinateWidth floatValue];
newCoord.longitude = [coordinateLength floatValue];

point.coordinate = newCoord;
point.title = vejNavn;
point.subtitle = detailText;

[mapView addAnnotation:point]
```

Comment: Where about you place the pins on the map. I mean is it in viewWillAppear or a method you are calling? Is it called only once? If you are adding that much annotations you should be adding your MKPointAnnotations to an array and then add them all together with [mapView addAnnotations:(NSArray)]

Comment: I have a method that gets called on ViewDidLoad. But i will look into MKPointAnnotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Suggestion

Try Google Maps SDK.

I have tried MapKit and Google Maps SDK, but Google Maps for me is better than MapKit.

Comment: Thanks, i will try that out too. I personally preffer Google Maps, but it was just easier to use MapKit. But thanks i will take a look at that :)

Comment: In fact Google Maps it's easier, just follow the Google Documentation which is full of examples.